# Por que se eu renomear a pasta os arquivos dentro dela mudam?

Tags: python, linux

Estou usando o lubuntu 17 e tinha uma pasta chamada images com alguns arquivos dai tava tentando renomear esses arquivos com esse programinha em python:

```
import os
import re


def repl(match):
    dic = {"4": "0", "5": "1", "6": "2", "7": "3", "Q": "4",
           "J": "5", "K": "6", "A": "7", "2": "8", "3": "9"}
    print(match.group()[0], dic[match.group()[0]])
    return "{}.".format(dic[match.group()[0]])


for name in os.listdir("pasta"):
    old_file = os.path.join("pasta", name)
    new_file = os.path.join("teste", re.sub(
        r"[A-Z0-9][.]", repl, name))
    os.rename(old_file, new_file)
```

Agora se eu renomear a pasta teste para images de novo os arquivos ficam trocados, vejam:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

por exemplo o 9 vira 3. Como eu resolvo isso?

Answer (score 0):

Você não criou sua função de renomear de forma que ela seja reversível - não é nenhuma surpresa que rodar duas vezes a mesma funcionalidade não vai restaurar os nomes originais.

O uso de expressões regulares, e subs aí é uma escolha que, embora talvez seja mais simples de implementar, prejudica a legibilidade do código. regexps são uma sub-linguagem dentro do Python, e a api dos objetos tipo "match" que você usa não é amigável a uma leitura por terceiros que não tenham ela na ponta da língua - por isso sua pergunta ficou sem resposta esse tempo todo.

Mas mesmo sem acompanhar seu programa passo a passo, é só ver que o seu dicionário transforma o "4" em "0", mas não há uma entrada reversa para mudar o "0" de volta pra "4". O "0" aliás não vai pra nada, isso deve dar um "keyerror" no dicionário e o programa para o processamento (por isso os nomes ficam os mesmos, e não mudam de novo para outra coisa).

Em suma: 
mude seu dicionário para que todas as mudanças tenham uma ida e uma volta simétrica, se quiser que isso aconteça - e mude a linha:

```
return "{}.".format(dic[match.group()[0]])
```

para:

```
value = match.group()[0]
return "{}.".format(dic.get(value, value))
```

O uso do método `.get` vai fazer o dicionário  não dar erro quando o valor não existir: ele retorna o segundo parâmetro, que é a própria letra (mude o print também).